# How to judge a URL is legal?

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

**The URL needs to follow the following rules：**

1. The hostname can only contain numbers,letters,"_","-","." and must contain a ".";
2. The protocol is not necessary;

I use the following regular expression:

```
/^(\w+\:(\/\/)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*(\/.*)?$/
```

Do you have a better idea?

Comment: 1. Hostnames cannot contain a ".", and 2. The protocol is necessary.

Comment: For what language are you constructing a regex?

Comment: Alternatively do a HEAD request to see if it returns 200

Comment: we can now parse with the browser: var a=document.createElement("a");a.href=url;alert(a.host);

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to remove the protocol I guess.

`\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]`